# «Офигенная кулстори» — это речевая избыточность?

Tags: выбор-слов

Вижу такое словосочетание в соцсетях. Начнем, пожалуй, с того, что ***кулстори*** — это крутая история (дословный перевод). Офигенная = крутая. Так зачем же автор этого сообщения решил добавить избыточное определение, а? И ещё интересно услышать мнение насчет самого слово. Видимо, люди уже активно употребляют это слово и в скором времени его добавят в словари. Или же нет?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса автора, продолжающего тему, не представляющей никакой языковой проблемы, кроме одной, той, что граничит с речью вульгарной или матерной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Признаться честно, я впервые слышу это слово. Даже в интернете мне не удалось найти определение этого слова - заголовки под этим именем приводят на какие-нибудь дурацкие, бессмысленные истории. Даже в Викисловаре его нет. Видимо, еще недостаточно широко распространилось это слово. Войдет это слово в словарь - не могу сказать точно, но не думаю. Что касается речевой избыточности, то из такого списка, как "памятные сувениры", " необычный феномен","движущий лейтмотив", "биография жизни","своя автобиография". В таких случаях говорят о скрытой тавтологии, так как русское слово повторяет значение заимствованного. Например, сувенир - французское слово, означающее "подарок на память", "вещь, связанная с воспоминаниями", и к нему еще добавляют памятный; биография - греческое слово, означающее "жизнеописание", автобиография - "жизнеописание какого-нибудь лица, составленная им самим", поэтому уточняющие слова при них неуместны.

Answer (score 3):

Такие вещи находятся на периферии стилистики... Ну, жаргонное слово. Ну, придали ему такое же жаргонное определение... а потом вдруг решили выяснить: а нет ли тут стилистической погрешности?! Офигительно смешно-с. )

Answer (score 0):

"Кулстори" — это, скорее, не оценка "офигенности", а определение содержания: "интересная жизненная история". Очень близкий синоним из русского языка — "байка". Разница в том, что байка может быть и "бродячей", "народной", а "кулстори" позиционируется как рассказ о произошедшем с самим рассказчиком или хотя бы с кем-то из его личных знакомых.

"Офигенная кулстори" — это "крутая, интересная, классная байка".